# How to trigger a button event for a dynamic button?

Tags: c#, button, event-handling

I have a minesweeper game. There is a board of dynamically created buttons. What I want to do is to open the entire board (basically to perform a click event to every single button).

I have tried to use the PerformClick method, but it did not work. Firstly, I used `btn.Click` event as `btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click)`, but I recently changed it to `btn.MouseUp` event because of the left / right click usage. Even when I used the `btn.Click` event, the PerformClick did not work.

```cs
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            GenerateMineSweeper();

            // my try of using PerfomClick
            for (int i = 0; i < this.Controls.Count; ++i)
            {
                if (this.Controls[i] is Button)
                {
                    Button btn = (Button)this.Controls[i];
                    btn.PerformClick();
                }
            }
        }

        private void GenerateMineSweeper()
        {
            // board is 15 x 25
            Point p = new Point(0, 0);
            for (int i = 1; i <= 15; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= 25; ++j)
                {
                    Button btn = new Button();

                    btn.Location = p;
                    btn.Size = new Size(25, 25);
                    btn.BackColor = Color.RoyalBlue;
                    btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;

                    // btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
                    btn.MouseUp += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        switch (e.Button)
                        {
                            case MouseButtons.Left:
                                btn_LeftClick(s, e);
                                break;
                            case MouseButtons.Right:
                                btn_RightClick(s, e);
                                break;
                        }
                    };

                    this.Controls.Add(btn);

                    p.X += 25;
                }
                p.Y += 25;
                p.X = 0;
            }
        }

        private void btn_LeftClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = sender as Button;
            // code
        }

        private void btn_RightClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // code
        }
```

**P.S. : Because I use MouseUp event, I obviously want a LeftClick event trigger, not a RightClick.**

EDIT: I also tried to do this as follows:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < this.Controls.Count; ++i)
{
    if (this.Controls[i] is Button)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)this.Controls[i];
        btn.MouseUp += btn_LeftClick;
    }
}
```

but I got a `StackOverflowException` (*An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll*).

Comment: What is the purpose of the PerformClick in the way you're trying to use it? You have the eventhandler commented out and I see no btn_click subroutine. Also, if you want to use MouseUp, you need to use MouseEventHandler instead of EventHandler. This will give you access to e.Button to determine what mouse button was used to trigger the event.

Comment: @CharlesMay Thank you for MouseEventHandler advice. I said that I have tried to use the PerformClick with the ```EventHandler(btn_Click)``` (without using the ```MouseUp``` event, but it did not work. My main project is more developed and I have reached to the point where if a player clicks on a bomb button, then the game ends up and the entire board should open (every button is pressed). I don't know how to do that and in that project I use ```MouseUp``` event because I need both right and left click events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some example code that should give you an idea for each thing you're trying to do

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        //Let's put 5 buttons on the form
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Location = new Point(10, i * 25);
        if (i == 2)
        {
            btn.Name = "Bomb";
        }
        else
        {
            btn.Name = "btn" + i;
        }
        btn.Text = "Closed";
        //Add a Click EventHandler
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        //Add a MouseUp MouseEventHandler
        btn.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(btn_MouseUp);
        //Add them to the form
        Controls.Add(btn);
    }
}

private void btn_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Button b = sender as Button;
    //Show me which button was used when this event was triggered
    //MessageBox.Show(e.Button.ToString() + " Mouse button was used.");

    //Since the Right button on mouseup will not be considered a Click, we can tell it to PerformClick
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        b.PerformClick();
    }
}
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    if (btn.Name == "Bomb" && gameOver == false)
    {
        gameOver = true;
        btn.Text = "Boom";
        ExplodeAll(btn);
    }
    else
    {
        btn.Text = "Opened";
    }
}

bool gameOver = false;
private void ExplodeAll(Button sender)
{
    foreach (Button b in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
    {
        if (b.Name.StartsWith("btn"))
        {
            b.PerformClick();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Added an `ExplodeAll` method that opens all buttons when a bomb is clicked. Clicking the 3rd button will simulate a bomb opening all buttons with the `.PerformClick()`